# Security Error with iframe

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, iframe, sencha-touch

The following issue occurs in Android 4.4 devices and above.

This is what our iframe looks like:

```
<iframe frameborder=0 id="myIFRAME"></iframe>
```

The following is the way we are getting iframe programmatically:

```
if(document.getElementById("myIFRAME")){
        me.setMyIFRAME(document.getElementById("myIFRAME").contentWindow);
}
```

This is causing a security error related to Protocol mismatch:

> "Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "https://www.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin "file://".
>   The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being
>   accessed has a protocol of "file". Protocols must match.

We are using Sencha touch with Cordova to develop our project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that iframe was loading html page which was accessing window.document which was causing Cross-domain security error
Below if condition was inside page

```
 if (window.parent.document != window.document)
```

we change it to below condition which resolve security error

```
if (window.parent != window)
```

Comment: Where i have to use this

Answer (score 4):

The [Cordova security guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_security_index.md.html#iframes-and-the-callback-id-mechanism) says:

> If content is served in an iframe from a whitelisted domain, that domain will have access to the native Cordova bridge.

Have you tried adding the external domain [to the whitelist](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide) inside `config.xml`?

```
<access origin="https://google.com" />
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ritika,
I'm taking a wild guess here, because I do not use iframes, but in your `<iframe>` element I do NOT see a `src`. As such, the system is setting it to some type of default and the protocol of that source is `file://`

I think if you set a `src=`, even a blank one, the issue will go away.

Away, just a guess. Best of Luck.

Comment: src is dynamically created in code & then is ultimately set on iframe.Even i tried to set src = '' initially, but that doesnt helped

Comment: Okay, Shot in the dark. Are you using the *white-list*, the plugin and CSP?

Comment: I have tried using whie-listing , that too doesnt help

Comment: Okay. A few more issues to try. Are you using an alternate webview library? Like crosswalk? You did not say if you are using CSP? Which version of the Cordova/phonegap compiler are you using? Which version of the plugin are you using? Have you tried the *minSDK* and *targetSDK*?

Answer (score 0):

1. Google is not accessible over iFrame.
2. From a page served using `file://` protocol cannot access resources over `http://` or `https://` protocol by default.

Answer (score 0):

Personaly, I would avoid using iFrames all together.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/iFrame-Usage